# More organized way to call Coroutines?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my code, I have multiple web requests needed to be called after the previous one is finished. For example:

```
void Init()
{
    StartCoroutine(FirstRequest());
}

IEnumerator FirstRequest()
{
    www = new WWW(my_url);
    yield return www;
    StartCoroutine(SecondRequest());
}

IEnumerator SecondRequest()
{
    www = new WWW(my_url);
    yield return www;
}
```

If the body of function is huge, it is relly easy to get confusing and messy,in Javascript, there is Promise, so I can do this:

```
function init() {  
  return validateParams()
    .then(firstRequest)
    .then(SecondRequest)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result)
      return result
    })
}
```

Any one has a clue how should I extend Coroutines so I can have similar effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very straightforward. Just use `yield return SecondRequest();` or  `yield return StartCoroutine( SecondRequest());`. The `yield` before the the coroutine name or `StartCoroutine` should make it wait for that coroutine to return before it continue to execute other code below it.

For example, you have four coroutine functions that should be called sequentially:

```
IEnumerator FirstRequest()
{
    www = new WWW(my_url);
    yield return www;
}

IEnumerator SecondRequest()
{
    www = new WWW(my_url);
    yield return www;
}

IEnumerator ThirdRequest()
{
    www = new WWW(my_url);
    yield return www;
}

IEnumerator FourthRequest()
{
    www = new WWW(my_url);
    yield return www;
}
```

*You can then do this*:

```
void Init()
{
    StartCoroutine(doSequentialStuff());
}

IEnumerator doSequentialStuff()
{
    //Do first request then wait for it to return
    yield return FirstRequest();

    //Do second request then wait for it to return
    yield return SecondRequest();

    //Do third request then wait for it to return
    yield return ThirdRequest();

    //Do fourth request then wait for it to return
    yield return FourthRequest();
}
```

---

**EDIT**:

> what if I only proceed to next coroutine if only I got success status?
>   like `www = new WWW(my_url); yield return www; if(!www.error)
>   StartCoroutine(SecondRequest());`

In this case, you should use `Action` as a parameter in the coroutine functions:

```
IEnumerator FirstRequest(Action<bool> reqStat)
{
    www = new WWW(my_url);
    yield return www;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        reqStat(false);
    else
        reqStat(true);
}

IEnumerator SecondRequest(Action<bool> reqStat)
{
    www = new WWW(my_url);
    yield return www;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        reqStat(false);
    else
        reqStat(true);
}

IEnumerator ThirdRequest(Action<bool> reqStat)
{
    www = new WWW(my_url);
    yield return www;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        reqStat(false);
    else
        reqStat(true);
}

IEnumerator FourthRequest(Action<bool> reqStat)
{
    www = new WWW(my_url);
    yield return www;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        reqStat(false);
    else
        reqStat(true);
}
```

*Usage*:

```
void Init()
{
    StartCoroutine(doSequentialStuff());
}

IEnumerator doSequentialStuff()
{
    bool reqStat = false;

    //Do first request then wait for it to return
    yield return FirstRequest((status) => { reqStat = status; });

    //Do second request then wait for it to return
    if (reqStat)
        yield return SecondRequest((status) => { reqStat = status; });

    //Do third request then wait for it to return
    if (reqStat)
        yield return ThirdRequest((status) => { reqStat = status; });

    //Do fourth request then wait for it to return
    if (reqStat)
        yield return FourthRequest((status) => { reqStat = status; });
}
```

Comment: what if I only proceed to next coroutine if only I got success status? like  www = new WWW(my_url);
    yield return www; if(!www.error)
    StartCoroutine(SecondRequest());

Comment: Are you sure it'll work that way? It looks like it'll only execute the inner coroutine until the first yield. There's just one in your code, but I think it'd break if there was a second.

Comment: @Arshia001 *"Are you sure it'll work that way?"* There are two solutions in my answer. I don't know which one you are referring but both of them should work.

Comment: Sorry, I was on my phone, I couldn't check to be sure. It's correct. My bad.