# Best practice for sequenced Coroutine management

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There are quite a bit of questions about managing your Coroutines here and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42965342/more-organized-way-to-call-coroutines) answer by [Programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3785314/programmer) made me start toying with it a bit. I threw together a little piece that will handle consequent progression of Coroutines, queuing and handling errors. It's simple enough and works fine but I found that it quickly became somewhat bloated and its features are limited. So my question; how would you improve this? Do you feel like it's a good solution? Is this even ever needed (I've never needed it but questions arise quite frequently)? I'm not very experienced with events, would events make a cleaner solution?

Features:

• Running coroutines in specific order

• Being able to abort or skip

• Handle invidivual coroutine statuses?

```
CoroutineStatus cont;

enum CoroutineStatus
{
    Continue,
    Skip,
    Abort
}

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(
        DoCoroutinesInOrder(
            (status, routine) =>
            {
                Debug.Log(routine.GetType().Name + " was " + status);
                // Handle every routines status. 
                // Not sure if this is a desired feature...
            },
            new IEnumerator[] {
                Routine1((status) => { cont = status; }),
                Routine2((status) => { cont = status; }),
                Routine3((status) => { cont = status; }),
            }
        )
    );
}


IEnumerator DoCoroutinesInOrder(Action<CoroutineStatus, IEnumerator> status, params IEnumerator[] routines)
{
    foreach (var routine in routines)
    {
        status(cont, routine);

        if (cont == CoroutineStatus.Continue)
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine(routine);
        }
        else if (cont == CoroutineStatus.Abort)
        {
            cont = CoroutineStatus.Continue;
            break;
        }
        else if (cont == CoroutineStatus.Skip)
        {
            cont = CoroutineStatus.Continue;
            continue;
        }
    }
}


IEnumerator Routine1(Action<CoroutineStatus> status)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    Debug.Log(1);
}
IEnumerator Routine2(Action<CoroutineStatus> status)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    Debug.Log(2);
    // something happened, abort progression
    status(CoroutineStatus.Abort);
}
IEnumerator Routine3(Action<CoroutineStatus> status)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    Debug.Log(3);
}
```