# Unity - Waiting for HTTP request to resolve

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the function, I am wondering if there is a more concise way of writing it:

```
private static WWW WaitUntilResolved (WWW request)
{
    bool success = true;
    float timeout = 5000, timer = 0;

    while (!request.isDone) {
        if (timer > timeout) {
            success = false;
            break;
        }
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (success && request.error == null)
        return request;
    else {
        request.Dispose ();
        return null;
    }
}
```

ps. WWW is a native unity class: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html

Comment: Your code is blocking in a poll-loop. This very undesirable. Is there a reason you can't use the non-blocking async `HttpClient` class?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Unity, is `WWW` a class in Unity or something else?

Comment: Also, please post your code in context. What code is calling `WaitUntilResolved`? Do you have multiple threads going on?

Comment: Unity has this in their tutorials.  You should use an Enumerator. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-RetrievingTextBinaryData.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are really using `WWW` and [`isDone`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-isDone.html) wrong. If you must use `isDone`, you must put it in while loop. You must also yield in the while loop with  `yield return null;` otherwise the game will freeze until the download is done. This whole thing requires [coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) so the function must be made a coroutine function.

You really don't need `isDone`. That's **only** used when you want to know the progress of the download.

Here is a proper way to use `isDone`:

```
private static IEnumerator WaitUntilResolved(WWW request)
{
    while (!request.isDone)
    {
        Debug.Log("Download Stat: " + request.progress);

        //Wait each frame in each loop OR Unity would freeze
        yield return null;
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.error))
    {
        //Success
    }
}
```

If you don't need to know the progress of the download then below is something you should use:

```
private static IEnumerator WaitUntilResolved(WWW request)
{
    yield return request;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.error))
    {
        //Success
    }
}
```

Finally, you cannot call a coroutine function directly. You have to use [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) function to do that:

```
WWW www = new WWW("www.yahoo.com");
StartCoroutine(WaitUntilResolved(www));
```

---

**EDIT:**

> How do I set a timeout for the coroutine?

Most `WebRequest` tutorials uses timer. You don't need to do that in Unity with the `WWW` API. It is not necessary here because this is a non blocking operation. If you must then see the code below.

```
private static IEnumerator WaitUntilResolved(WWW request)
{
    float timeout = 5000, timer = 0;

    while (!request.isDone)
    {
        Debug.Log("Download Stat: " + request.progress);

        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (timer >= timeout)
        {
            Debug.Log("Timeout happened");
            //Break out of the loop
            yield break;
        }
        //Wait each frame in each loop OR Unity would freeze
        yield return null;
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.error))
    {
        //Success
    }
}
```

If you need to return the status of the download, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42965496/3785314) post that explains how to do that.

Comment: How do I set a timeout for the coroutine?

Comment: @Ja.L You  **don't** need a timeout. You only need it if `WWW` is not async. See the edited answer for more info.

Comment: If I set the return type to IEnumerator then I can no longer return a WWW object?

Comment: No. Not directly since it has to be an `IEnumerator`. Although I provided a link at the end of the answer that shows how to return a value with `Action` as parameter. You can add `Action` as extra parameter. The example I linked returns `bool` from the coroutine with `Action<bool> reqStat` but you can make it return `WWW` with `Action<WWW> reqStat`. I will leave that for you to do.

Comment: Should I call WWW.dispose() on timeout/error or is it not necessary?

Comment: You don't have to call that function.

Comment: With UnityWebRequest while loop with !isDone is correct, yielding the request is giving unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of waiting for async call.

```
string WebGet()
{
    Response result = new Response();
    IEnumerator e = GetStuff(result);

    // blocks here until UnityWebRequest() completes
    while (e.MoveNext());

    Debug.Log(result.result);
}

public class Response
{
    public string result = "";
}

IEnumerator GetStuff(Response res)
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://some.add.com/");

    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    while (!www.isDone)
        yield return true;

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        res.result = www.error;
    else
        res.result = www.downloadHandler.text;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but gives `uncaught exception: abort("Cannot enlarge memory arrays`...