# Unity - www.isDone always return false

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, ienumerator

I'm looking for a solution for this since last week, but all the solutions I tried did not work.

I'm trying to do apperantly a simple thing. I need to stop the game execution until I have a response from the server when in WebGL mode. I need this because I have to display a message for the player in case of failure of the sent tentative.

I'm trying to do this by using `WWW` class together with an `IEnumerator` method. I can't start the `IEnumarator` method by calling `StartCoroutine` on it because doing so, the next line starts executing immediatly. So I'm only declaring a variable of IEnumerator type and calling `MoveNext` method.

Follow my approach:

```
public class ServerOperations
{
    //...
    private int failed;

    public void RegisterPlay()
    {
        //...
        IEnumerator e = uploadFile(resultsFileName, resultsFileContent);
        while (e.MoveNext());
        //...
    }

    IEnumerator uploadFile(string fileName, string contentFile)
    {
        //...
        WWW www = new WWW(URL, formData);
        yield return www;
    
        while (!www.isDone)
        {
            Debug.Log("Not done");
            yield return true;
        }
    
        if (www.error != null) {
            Debug.Log ("file " + fileName + " w.error = " + www.error);
            failed = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            failed = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The file was sent, but `www.isDone` never becomes `true`, and the game crashes with out of memory exception.

I'm following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682376/unity-waiting-for-http-request-to-resolve) in my implementation.

Why I my server receives the file and `www.isDone` never becomes true?

Comment: Never used that library but in the documentation of WWW (apart from saying that its obsolete nowadays), it says that the property .isDone is changed in case the download of a file finishes, but from what I can read in your question, you're actually uploading a file to a server, right?

Answer (score 2):

Straight away I can see 2 problems here.

First, WWW class is obsolete. What you should use is UnityWebRequest. Check out [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html), I think this example does exactly what you are looking for.

Second, uploadFile is a couroutine, and looks like you are running it from non coroutine context, which normally should just skip the execution, do nothing at all, so it is strange you are saying you managed to upload something. Anyways, what you should do is run it with StartCoroutine. This will of cause start it asynchronously. On Update() callback you can check if your operation is done.

```
 private WWW www = null; // Make sure to declare it outside the function

 public void RegisterPlay() {
     StartCoroutine(uploadFile(...));
     .....
 }

 private void Update() {
     if (www && www.isDone) {
         www = null; // Zero it to avoid double completion
         // Here you know it is done, continue your code
     }
 }
```

Comment: The problem with this solution, is that I need to halt the program while the upload doesn't finish. Calling `StartCoroutine(uploadFile(...))` the next line starts to execute.

Comment: It is not a problem. You cannot call coroutine as a regular function, period, will not work. If youy want to halt that code until coroutine completes, the code that calls it should be couroutine itself. Alternatively you can use start couroutine and check if it has completed from Update() function.

Comment: How can I do this? Check if the coroutine is completed?

Comment: I added some schematic example, see the answer. I also suggest you read about coroutines to make sure you understand the principle, here is a good article https://gamedevbeginner.com/coroutines-in-unity-when-and-how-to-use-them/