# Unity Using IENumerator to set a class that another object will use

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I am trying to create an object from my DB that another class uses. 
But there seems to be a problem due to the delayed response from the IEnumerator (maybe?).

We have a very simple enemy class to parse a json to:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Enemy{
 public string EnemyID;
 public string Name;
}
```

the BattleManager is attached to an object in the scene

```
public class BattleManager : Monobehaviour{

 public Enemy debugEnemy;

 void start()
 {
   //get a reference to the DBAccess
   DBA = GameObject.Find("ManagerDB").GetComponent<DBAccess>();

   debugEnemy = DBA.GetEnemy(1);
   //debugEnemy EnemyID=0 and Name=""
   //This is where the Problem is! Why is this not set from my DB?
 }
}
```

Now here is where I get info from the database. Everything seems to go properly except GetEnemy returns a default Enemy Object instead of the one with its variables loaded from the json in the IEnumerator GetEnemyFromDB

```
public class DBAccess: Monobehaviour{

 private Enemy enemy;

 public Enemy GetEnemy(int EnemyID)
 {
   enemy = new Enemy();
   StartCoroutine(GetEnemyFromDB(EnemyID));

   //HERE enemy.EnemyID is 0 and enemy.Name is ""
   return enemy;
 }
 private IEnumerator GetEnemyFromDB(int EnemyID)
 {
     WWWForm postData = new WWWForm();
     postData.AddField("EnemyID", EnemyID);

     WWW dbProc = new WWW(GetEnemyURL, postData);
     yield return dbProc;

     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbProc.error)) //error is null or empty so: SUCCESS!
     {
         string jsonstring = "{\"Items\":" + dbProc.text + "}";

         Enemy[] EnemiesFromDB;
         EnemiesFromDB = JsonHelper.FromJson<Enemy>(jsonstring);

         if (EnemiesFromDB.Length > 0)
         {
             enemy = EnemiesFromDB[0];
             //HERE enemy.EnemyID is 1 and enemy.Name is "Evil Enemy Monster Man!"
             //So it is working here!
         }
         else throw new System.Exception("No Enemy Found When Reading Json: " + JsonUtility.FromJson<Enemy>(jsonstring));

     }
     else throw new System.Exception("DB ERROR: " + dbProc.error);
 }

}
```

I found this helper class here on stackoverflow. I forget where or I would give proper credit, but it works great!

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
 public static string RemoveBrackets(string s)
 {
    s = s.Replace("[", string.Empty);
    s = s.Replace("]", string.Empty);
    return s;
 }

 public static T[] FromJson<T>(string json)
 {

    Wrapper<T> wrapper = JsonUtility.FromJson<Wrapper<T>>(json);
    return wrapper.Items;
 }

 public static string ToJson<T>(T[] array)
 {
    Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<T>();
    wrapper.Items = array;
    return JsonUtility.ToJson(wrapper);
 }

 public static string ToJson<T>(T[] array, bool prettyPrint)
 {
    Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<T>();
    wrapper.Items = array;
    return JsonUtility.ToJson(wrapper, prettyPrint);
 }

 [System.Serializable]
 private class Wrapper<T>
 {
    public T[] Items;
 }
}
```

Super frustrating, I think I have read a million posts on IEnumerator.
I wish I could just have the IEnumerator method return my Enemy object instead of having private enemy as variable that is effected by the IEnumerator and returned by the getter method.

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non coroutine function cannot wait for a coroutine function. If you try to force this then you would need to do that with a boolean variable in the `Update` function every frame. I wouldn't suggest that. Making a web request with the `WWW` API takes several frames or so. This means that the `GetEnemyFromDB` function call has not yet finished or returned before you tried to access the value.

In your case, you have to make the following changes:

**1**. You have to make the `GetEnemy` function a coroutine function so that you can wait for the `GetEnemyFromDB` function until it's done. This is done with the `yield return`  statement.

**2**. To set Object in a parameter in a coroutine function use `Action`. In this case, `Action<Enemy> enemyResult` is appropriate.

**3**. Change the `Start` function to a coroutine function. Yes, you can do that. It's one of the few Unity's callback functions that can be made into a coroutine function. Note that it's `Start` not `start` as you put in the code from your question.

Your new `BattleManager` class:

```
public class BattleManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Enemy debugEnemy;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        //get a reference to the DBAccess
        DBAccess DBA = GameObject.Find("ManagerDB").GetComponent<DBAccess>();
        yield return StartCoroutine(DBA.GetEnemy(1, (result) => { debugEnemy = result; }));

        //YOU CAN NOW USE debugEnemy below

    }
}
```

Your new `DBAccess` class:

```
public class DBAccess : MonoBehaviour
{
    public IEnumerator GetEnemy(int EnemyID, Action<Enemy> enemyResult)
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine(GetEnemyFromDB(EnemyID, enemyResult));
    }

    private IEnumerator GetEnemyFromDB(int EnemyID, Action<Enemy> enemyResult)
    {
        WWWForm postData = new WWWForm();
        postData.AddField("EnemyID", EnemyID);

        WWW dbProc = new WWW(GetEnemyURL, postData);
        yield return dbProc;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbProc.error)) //error is null or empty so: SUCCESS!
        {
            string jsonstring = "{\"Items\":" + dbProc.text + "}";

            Enemy[] EnemiesFromDB;
            EnemiesFromDB = JsonHelper.FromJson<Enemy>(jsonstring);

            if (EnemiesFromDB.Length > 0)
            {
                //Pass result back to param
                if (enemyResult != null)
                    enemyResult(EnemiesFromDB[0]);

                //HERE enemy.EnemyID is 1 and enemy.Name is "Evil Enemy Monster Man!"
                //So it is working here!
            }
            else throw new System.Exception("No Enemy Found When Reading Json: " + JsonUtility.FromJson<Enemy>(jsonstring));

        }
        else throw new System.Exception("DB ERROR: " + dbProc.error);
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it! That is absolutely amazing, you can return an object from an IEnumerator. Time to study up what the heck an Action is! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I used [Action](https://www.dotnetperls.com/action) and lambda to return the result in a coroutine function. That's what you should be doing when you need to return a result from a coroutine function.

Comment: Actually, there is no need for Start amd GetEnemy to be a coroutine themselves. You can just call them as basic methods with the current code. Now it is "stalling" in start while not necessary since the waiting code is in the callback. Making Start and GetEnemy void method will make the same result. Does not mean it is currently wrong, just it could be simplified to my opinion.

Comment: @Everts That's totally true. Although I have my own reason for doing it this way. The reason is that `GetEnemy` needs to be a `void` function since it can't return `Enemy` as it is in the question. Instead of telling OP to change the return type to `void`, I decided to change it to `IEnumerator` which is like killing two birds with one stone

Comment: If you look at the code in the `Start` function, you will see that OP wants to use the result after `GetEnemy(1)` is called and under it. I also expect OP to do more things in order, under there after retrieving the data. If I did it the way you mentioned, the rest of OP's code after the request is done would be required to be placed inside lambda like this `DBA.GetEnemy(1,(result)=>{ LONG CODE }` .

Comment: If OP wants to make another web request  with your suggestion, that would be lambda inside lambada and things would get messy and ugly from there. This is more organized way to do that than using nested lambdas.See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42965496/3785314) answer I made for example then look at the Javascript code in that question. That's what it would look like. I jut wanted OP to be able to use it the-same way he wanted instead of moving the rest of the code that depends on that data into lambda. No "stalling".Coroutine is just waiting for the request before you can use the result

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that StartCorutine does not block execution, problem is here:

```
 public Enemy GetEnemy(int EnemyID)
 {
   enemy = new Enemy();
   StartCoroutine(GetEnemyFromDB(EnemyID)); //this is executed asynchronously
   return enemy;
 }
```

you need to change it to:

```
public void GetEnemy(int EnemyID, Action<Enemy> callback)
{
    StartCoroutine(GetEnemyFromDB(EnemyID,callback));
}

private IEnumerator GetEnemyFromDB(int EnemyID, Action<Enemy> callback)
{
    WWWForm postData = new WWWForm();
    postData.AddField("EnemyID", EnemyID);

    WWW dbProc = new WWW(GetEnemyURL, postData);
    yield return dbProc; //code below is executed later, after after receiving the response from the server

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbProc.error)) //error is null or empty so: SUCCESS!
    {
        string jsonstring = "{\"Items\":" + dbProc.text + "}";
        Enemy[] EnemiesFromDB;
        EnemiesFromDB = JsonHelper.FromJson<Enemy>(jsonstring);
        if (EnemiesFromDB.Length > 0)
        {
            var enemy = EnemiesFromDB[0];
            callback(enemy); //return enemy
            yield break;
        }
        else
            Debug.LogError("Enemy does not exist");
    }
    else
        Debug.LogError("WWW request failed: " + dbProc.error);
    callback(null); //call empty calbback to inform that something has failed
 }
```

and use that this way:

```
public class BattleManager : Monobehaviour{

 public Enemy debugEnemy;

 void Start()
 {
   //get a reference to the DBAccess
   DBA = GameObject.Find("ManagerDB").GetComponent<DBAccess>();

   debugEnemy = DBA.GetEnemy(1,(e)=>{
      if(e!=null)
      {
      //Do something with enemy here, it will be couple frames later
      }
   });
 }
}
```